# Need to Close the div in if condition MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to close a div inside the if condition which is inside a foreach loop.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.modal)
{
    counter++; 
    <div class="Class1">
        <div class="span6">
            <!-- block -->
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <div class="left">
                        @item["Topic"];</div>
                </div>
                <div class="collapsein">
                    @item["Desc"];</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @if (counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            </div>
        }
            
}
```

I am getting this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Source Error:

```
Line 33:         int counter = 0;
Line 34:     }
Line 35:     @foreach (var item in ViewBag.modal)
Line 36:     {
Line 37:         counter++;
```

Source File: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml    Line: 35

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

Comment: Try `@if (counter % 2 == 0) { @:<div> }`

Comment: Same error is coming.. if i close div outside of if condition its working fine. but i want it to close inside if condition only.

Comment: But that means you need to start the `<div>` in a `if` block as well

Comment: I think I understand what your trying to do. As a simple test add the following to your view - `<div> @for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) { <span>@i</span> if(i % 2 == 0) { @:</div><div> } }</div>`

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: The code I gave you in the snippet works fine (tested it). What do you mean _"Still the same issue"_?

Comment: The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: Have you commented out or removed your code from the view (which does not work - hence the error!) - I gave your that snippet so you could test how do do it correctly

Comment: I have removed my code and paste the code snippet which u gave. And i am getting this error. Thanks for ur response. Parser Error Message: The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.


Source Error: 


Line 56:     }
Line 57: 
Line 58:     <div> @for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) { <span>@i</span> if(i % 2 == 0) { @:</div><div> } }</div>
Line 59:

Comment: Interesting - either you have not copied the code exactly or you have other code in the view causing the error.

Comment: I have copied your code snippet exactly the same and i don't have any other code in my view

Comment: OK thanks.. let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this, run two loops one for total and one for two items. so this condition of loose close elements will not occur.

```
@for (int count = 0; count <= ViewBag.modal.Count; count++)
{
    <div class="Class1">
        @for (int counter = 0; counter < 2 && (count + counter - 1) <= ViewBag.modal.Count; counter++)
        {
            <div class="span6">
                <!-- block -->
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="block-header">
                        <div class="left">
                            @ViewBag.modal[count]["Topic"]
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapsein">
                        @ViewBag.modal[count]["Desc"]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to wrap it as a raw html!

change-

```
 @if (counter % 2 == 0)
        {
            </div>
        }
```

**To-**

```
@if (counter % 2 == 0)
     {
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
     }
```

Also I see that the main container `Class1` is not closed within the loop.